# Start Visual Studio without StartWindow

Tags: automation, visual-studio-2019, envdte

I need a programmatically start Visual Studio (devenv.exe) and open solution. I use EnvDte.
The problem is that EnvDTE.DTE.Solution.Open works, but StartWindow don't hide. If I click "Continue without code", I'll see the opened solution.
How can I programmatically close StartWindow?
[image: StartWindow]

Comment: Can't you simply use Process.Start using a ProcessStartInfo that targets the sln file and using OPEN verb ? CF https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.verb?view=net-5.0#remarks

Comment: No, in this case I can't guarantee Visual Studio version will start. I need an exact one.

Comment: in the registry you have install path for each version of installed Visual Studio. If you need a specific version you can join this path + common7\idde\devenv.exe and start a process

Comment: It's not working. For use Verb I must set FileName for process to sln, not exe.

Answer (score 4):

You can customize it by setting the **Startup** option:

Click **Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Startup**

For **On startup, open** option select "**Empty environment**".

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't find the way to close StartWindow programmatically.
The best one is to launch devenv.exe with */command* argument:

```
devenv.exe /command "File.OpenProject {pathToSolution}"
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/command-devenv-exe?view=vs-2019
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/visual-studio-commands?view=vs-2019